# Entre hommes ou entre les hommes?

Tags: articles, absence-d-article

I'm learning French using Duolingo, and somewhere one of its sentences is:

> Nous sommes entre hommes.

Why there is no articles after entre and before hommes? Is it optional?

Comment: I need to think more about the why, but the article is not optional, it's forbidden (if you mean “among men”/“between men”). “Entre les hommes” would mean between the (presumably two) specific men that were previously mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an option. It depends on what *entre* is used for.
This preposition may be used for 2 distinct meanings a) between two limits or b) to express a relationship (reciprocity or opposition) inside a set.
In the first case, we most of the time use the article :

> Je marche entre le mur et l'arbre.
>   Je marche entre les hommes réunis dans cette salle.

Except if the limits are related to time or are abstractions:

> Je viendrai entre 4 et 5 heures.
>    J'aime cette couleur entre rouge et violet.

In the second case, when *entre* expresses a reciprocity, we don't use articles :

> Cela se passe entre hommes (ou femmes).
>   Nous sommes entre amis.

When it expresses an opposition, we do use articles :

> Il hésite entre le bien et le mal.
>   La concurence entre la route et le train.
>   Seule entre les autres femmes, elle portait fièrement un pantalon.

Particular case : *entre autres* (among others, inter alea)

> Vous devrez fournir, entre autres, votre date de naissance.

A little bit complicated ? No, not at all ! ;)