# Quels articles suivent la préposition "entre" ? Pourquoi l'article zéro ?

Tags: prépositions, articles, absence-d-article

I have a question concerning the usage of l'article zéro et l'article défini after the preposition "entre"
I have seen many examples of both, yet I don't know which one would be more accurate to use.

"entre fatigue et maux de têtes" (From the song "Belle" from Naika)
(-pourqoui pas "*entre la fatigue et les maux de tête*" ?)
"Elle est coincé entre les pays, les relations et les identités" (dans le sens "confus")
(est-ce qu'on peut dire aussi *entre pays, relations et identité/entre des pays, des relation et des identités* ?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entre hommes ou entre les hommes?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27749/entre-hommes-ou-entre-les-hommes)

Comment: @livresque Cela ne répond pas à la question posée ici.

Comment: Bienvenue !  J'ai tenté de clarifier le titre de la question mais si tu n'es pas d'accord, tu peux tout changer : )

Answer (score -1):

> Le nom sans déterminant (= déterminant zéro ) existe dans les cas
> suivants …
>
> 1)- Quand le nom est attribut.
>
> Exemple : Son frère est avocat.
>
> 2)- Quand il est apposé.
>
> Exemple : Informaticien, il n’a aucun problème à dépanner son
> ordinateur.
>
> 3)- Quand il est épithète d’un autre nom.
>
> Exemples : un enfant roi , une visite surprise
>
> 4)- **Quand il est placé après une préposition.**
>
> Exemple : Il travaille sans méthode.
>
> 5)- Quand il se désigne lui même. (On dit que c’est un nom autonyme)
> [...]

[absence de déterminant](https://www.jerevise.fr/absence-determinant-nom-commun-grammaire.html)

**Entre fatigue et maux de têtes** [**placé après une préposition**.]

Le mot *entre* est un préposition.

Voici un article plus élaboré sur cette même question:
[Omission de l'article ou l'article zéro](https://www.cairn.info/revue-ela-2016-2-page-139.htm)

Comment: Ce n'est pas exact ; on ne dirait jamais « Regardez dans la penderie, il y a un gilet entre robe bleue et pantalon rouge. ». On utilise toujours un article.

Comment: @LPH Mais non. ce n'est pas toujours le cas. Et si la chanson le dit, c'est bien pour cela.

Comment: Vous dites que « le nom sans déterminant (= déterminant zéro ) existe dans les cas suivants…Quand il est placé après une préposition ». C'est faux.  On ne trouve en aucun cas « Il y a des bancs entre arbres » ; c'est toujours « Il y a des bancs entre **les** arbres. ». « après _certaines_ prepositions _et dans certains cas_ » est correct, mais c'est tout (ex. : ils étaient entre amis).

Comment: Une ville **entre terre et mer** https://www.marseille.fr/decouvrir-marseille/une-ville-de-tourisme/une-ville-entre-terre-et-mer // **Entre amis**, aussi. Donc, le nom sans déterminant: placé après une préposition.

Comment: Ce n'est pas ce cas-là. On peut très bien dire dans la chanson « entre la fatigue et les maux de tête », et on peut aussi dire  « Une ville entre la terre et la mer  » ; seulement, on ne dira jamais « entre les amis », par exemple ; il s'agit là d'une certaine préposition (réciprocité, pas position) et de plus l'expression est figée (on dit par exemple « entre les délégués ouvriers et nous »). Le point de vue que que « entre » suivi d' un nom sans article renvoi à la notion de base du mot, qui est la votre ne me semble pas sans idée, mais c'est le votre (1/2)

Comment: et il ne s'applique pas de toute façon puisque on peut dans ce cas particulier utiliser l'article sans ajouter ou supprimer de nuance. (2/2)

Comment: Il ne s'agit pas de savoir pourquoi on **peut dire la fatigue et les maux de tête**. Il s'agit de savoir quand et pourquoi on **peut dire fatigue et maux de têtes** **sans déterminants**. On dit "entre amis" parce que **cela suit la règle**: placé après une préposition.

Comment: La réponse est qu'on peut le dire dans certains cas, comme celui de la chanson, lorsque les groupes sont reliés par une conjonction de coordination.

Comment: Tu utilise le même document que moi. Mais la règle que tu cite n'est pas la bonne ici.

Comment: La règle est dans la référence que vous avez utilisée et que j'ai aussi choisie (CAIRN :  [avant et] après des conjonctions de coordination (et, ou, ni) ) ; il se trouve que l'usage détaillé n'est pas inclu ; personnellement je ne le connais pas très bien. Par exemple, voilà un cas (première occurrence, non, seconde, oui) : « Il m'a dit qu'il y avait du pain sur la table et sur le buffet ; quand je suis arrivé il n'y avait sur table et buffet que des assiettes vides. ».

Answer (score -1):

This is not a problem that has to do with the preposition "entre"; it is strictly connected to the use of "et".

> ([Cairn](https://www.cairn.info/revue-ela-2016-2-page-139.htm)) En grammaire du français langue étrangère, l’absence de l’article est répertoriée (avec parfois mention de l’article zéro)
> – [avant et] Après des conjonctions de coordination (et, ou, ni) : Fromage ou dessert, fromage et dessert, ni vin ni bière.

This omission is not compulsory. Both possibilities are correct.

- Entre (la) fatigue et (les)  maux de tête il ne lui restait que peu de temps vraiment à elle.

> ([Cairn](https://www.cairn.info/revue-ela-2016-2-page-139.htm))
>
> –  Dans les énumérations : Tables, chaises, commodes, tapis… tout avait été enlevé

- "Elle est coincé entre les pays, les relations et les identités" (dans le sens "confus") (est-ce qu'on peut dire aussi entre pays, relations et identité/entre des pays, des relation et des identités ?)

"Confus" is probably a literal translation of "confused", and as such it is not correct. What is meant is something like "désorientée". In this particular case, the only choice is to use no articles.

- Elle est coincée entre  pays, relations et identités.

Comment: Après des conjonctions de coordination (et, ou, ni) : Fromage ou dessert, fromage et dessert, ni vin ni bière. ne s'applique pas ici. // "entre" n'est pas une conjonction de coordination. Et il n'y a pas des énumerations, non plus.

Comment: « Et » dans « fatigue **et** maux de têtes » est le mot qu'il faut reconnaitre. « Entre » n'a rien à voir. Le PO ne sait pas ; il/elle pense que ça vient de « entre » mais ce n'est pas la source du principe.

Comment: Non, c'est parce que "entre" suivi d' un nom sans article renvoi à la notion de base du mot. Comme bien d'autres noms avec une préposition et sans article.  Pour ton "on ne dirait jamais", en voici un autre: Vous prenez fromage et dessert, Madame? Bien sûr que non: Vous prenez le fromage et le dessert, Madame? Ah oui.